# Submission on refresh problem, how to obtain it without using the header function

Tags: php, refresh

Here's my problem:

I've been not able to prevent a submission on a page refresh. I'm creating a small app for a game but my problem is that, everytime I'm refreshing my page, my data form will be submitted to the main page so my record will go crazy.

Here's my code:

index.php

```
<?php

$_SESSION = [];
$title = 'Index';

?>

<div class="container" id="signin">
   <div>
      <div>
         <form action="untitled.php" method="POST" data-parsley-validate="">
            <label>Nome :</label><input type="text" name="username" class="box" required data-parsley-error-message="Inserisci il tuo username">
            <label>Password :</label><input type="password" name="password" class="box" required data-parsley-error-message="Inserisci la tua password">
            <?php
            if(isset($_GET["errors"])) {
               foreach ($_GET["errors"] as $value) {
                  echo '<p>'.$value.'</p>';
               }
            }
            ?>
            <input type="submit" value="Entra!" name="submit">
         </form>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

untitled.php

```
<?php

session_start();

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
  var_dump(isset($_POST['submit']));
  die();
  $myusername = $_POST['username'];
  $mypassword = $_POST['password'];

  $sql = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = ?');
  $sql->bindValue(1, $myusername, PDO::PARAM_STR);
  $sql->execute();

  $rows = $sql->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_NUM);

  if (empty($rows)) {

    $errors = array(
      "username" => "Non ci sono corrispondenze con il tuo username, riprova per piacere"
    );

    $queries = array(
      "errors" => $errors
    );

    $queryString = http_build_query($queries);

    session_destroy();
    header("Location: index.php?" . $queryString);

  } elseif ($rows[0][3] == $myusername && $rows[0][4] == $mypassword) {
    echo '<pre>';
    var_dump($_SESSION);
    echo '</pre>';
    $_SESSION['error_username'] = null;
    $_SESSION['error_password'] = null;
    $_SESSION['login_user'] = $myusername;
    $_SESSION['user_id'] = $rows[0][0];
    $_SESSION['id'] = session_id();
    $_SESSION['time'] = time();
    $_SESSION['attempt_quantity'] = 0;

    function getrandomimage() {
      $imageplay = ['400.png', '500.png', 'sorry.png'];
      $randKeys = array_rand($imageplay, 1);
      return $_SESSION['getrandomimage'] = $imageplay[$randKeys];
    }

    getrandomimage();

    $sql2 = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM myAttempts WHERE username_id = ?');
    $sql2->bindValue(1, $_SESSION['user_id'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $sql2->execute();

    $rows2 = $sql2->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM);

    if(empty($rows2)) {
      $sql = "INSERT INTO myAttempts (username_id, session_id, attempt_username, time_attempt, attempt_quantity) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)";

      $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);

      $stmt->execute([$_SESSION['user_id'], $_SESSION['id'], $_SESSION['login_user'], $_SESSION['time'], $_SESSION['attempt_quantity']]);

      $pdo = null;
      $stmt = null;

    } else {
      if ($rows2[5] > 10) {
        header("location: index.php");
      } else {
        $sql3 = "UPDATE myAttempts SET attempt_quantity = attempt_quantity + 1 WHERE username_id='".$_SESSION['user_id']."'";

        $pdo->query($sql3);
        $pdo = null;
        $stmt = null;

      }

    }

  } elseif ($rows[0][3] == $myusername && $rows[0][4] !== $mypassword) {

    $errors = array(
      "password" => "la tua password potrebbe essere errata",
    );

    $queries = array(
      "errors" => $errors
    );

    $queryString = http_build_query($queries);

    session_destroy();
    header("Location: index.php?" . $queryString);
  }

} else {
  header("location: index.php");
}

?>
```

The logic is pretty straightforward. Before I was using the function header("location: another_page.php") to run the code in another page to avoid the refresh problem, but in that way I wasn't able to catch the $_POST variable for some reason.

Now my goal is only to change the behavior of this snippet without javascript:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
  var_dump(isset($_POST['submit']));
die();
```

The problem is that this variable will be evaluated always true on refresh for some reason, which I want to avoid. Any idea?

Comment: I'm not getting the issue you're having with the `header()`-function? That should be done in the end so why would you need the `$_POST`-data after that? Make a request to your php-file, do what needs to be done with the posted data and when you're finished, redirect the client.

Comment: Or a better solution would be to use Ajax, if possible. Then the page won't reload at all. If you're talking about keeping the post data to repopulate the form, you can put the posted data into a session variable and use that to repopulate the form and clear that session variable after (like flash-sessions), I would opt in for using Ajax though

Comment: I know, I'm just looking for something easy to prevent the form resubmission on reload, but I haven't found anything yet..

Comment: The way it's done is using header() so that's probably why it's hard to find an alternative.

Comment: Fair enough, I will rewrite my code.. if there's no other option..

Comment: If you remove the `die();` and let the page actually complete the redirect back to `index.php`, then you shouldn't have an issue.  You would only see a refresh being problematic if you stay on untitled.php

Comment: how can I catch the if(isset($_POST['submit']))? it will always be evalutated false!

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.  `if(isset($_POST['submit']))` should really _never_ be false, unless you're loading untitled.php directly.  And what exactly do you mean by "catch the $_POST variable"?